# nodejs: child_process.spawn not reporting exit code

Tags: javascript, node.js, exit, child-process

While writting unit tests for a simple tool, I was unable to get the process exit code of a child process started with `require('child_process').spawn`. To simplify if down, consider this simple node command which exits with code 35:

```
SHELL> node -e "process.exit(35)" &
[1] 23427
[1]+  Saída 35               node -e "process.exit(35)"
```

Now consider the following file, where the command above is executed with `exec` and with `spawn`. The target is catching the exit code:

```
SHELL> cat WTF.js 
var cp = require('child_process');

cp.exec('node -e "process.exit(35);"', function(err){
  console.log('child exit code (exec)', err.code);
});

cp.spawn('node', ['-e', '"process.exit(35);"']).on('exit', function(code){
  console.log('child exit code (spawn)', code);
});
```

But when it's run... surprise:

```
SHELL> node WTF.js
child exit code (exec) 35
child exit code (spawn) 0
```

Am I missing something about the [spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) call?

```
SHELL> node --version 
v6.0.0
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the double quotes from the second parameter for `spawn()`, the `spawn()` will automatically take care of making sure the parameter is not accidentally separated due to spaces, etc:

```
cp.spawn('node', ['-e', 'process.exit(35);'])
  .on('exit', function(code){
    console.log('child exit code (spawn)', code);
  });
```

Otherwise node treats the passed (js) code literally as `"process.exit(35);"` (a string literal) which is basically a no-op and so it exits with code 0.

Comment: Awesome! Works as expected.